# ngx-editor doesn't clear value

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-editor

Nxg-editor ([docs](https://sibiraj-s.github.io/ngx-editor/#/quickstart)) can't clear its value on submit.

I have a code like this in the `form` tag, but when I click on method using `form.reset()` it doesn't clear the value of the editor. In fact, the value in the `form` is clear, but not on the DOM structure (it has a `<p>` tag with previous content).

How to remove all content from it?

I've tried `this.editor.destroy()` and `this.editor = new Editor();` but it doesn't help

[image]

```
<ngx-editor-menu
    [editor]="editor"
    [toolbar]="toolbar">
</ngx-editor-menu>
<ngx-editor
    [editor]="editor"
    formControlName="answer">
</ngx-editor>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-editor-eqktlc?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    this.editor.setContent('');
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?